# Properly rendering LatheGeometry in three.js

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js

I'm working on a little side project and I'm not understanding how to properly render the LatheGeometry shape in three.js. I've tried with the other shapes and I'm able to manipulate those without much trouble. Here is my code (pretty much the starter example from the docs):

```
    var scene = new THREE.Scene();
    var points = [];
    for ( var i = 0; i < 10; i ++ ) {
        points.push( new THREE.Vector2( Math.sin( i * 0.2 ) * 10 + 5, ( i - 5 ) * 2 ) );
    }
    var geometry = new THREE.LatheBufferGeometry( points );
    var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0xffff00 } );
    var lathe = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );

    var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000 );

    var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
    renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
    document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

    scene.add( lathe );


    camera.position.z = 5;
```

Comment: When and where do you call `renderer.render(scene, camera)`? And it would be better to put your camera a bit further, for example `camera.position.z = 100`

Comment: @prisoner849 I don't think I call that anywhere. I tried the camera suggestion to no avail.

Comment: So, what's your question then?

Comment: @prisoner849 I can't get LatheGeometry to appear on my page. How can I do that?

Comment: so show your real code